# xmltodict does not return a list for one element

Tags: python, list, xmltodict

The following Code produces an error, if there is only one "car" in "garage":

```
import xmltodict

mydict = xmltodict.parse(xmlstringResults)    
for carsInGarage in mydict['garage']['car']:
    # do something...
```

The Reason is that `mydict['garage']['car']` is only a list if there is more than one element of "car". So I did something like this:

```
import xmltodict

mydict = xmltodict.parse(xmlstringResults)
if isinstance(mydict['garage']['car'], list):
    for carsInGarage in mydict['garage']['car']:
        # do something for each car...
else:
    # do something for the car
```

to get the code to run. But for more advanced operations this is no solution.

Does someone know some kind of function to use, even if there is only one element?

Comment: Do not use reserved keywords like `dict` as your variable names!

Comment: If [`xmltodict`](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) returns a single car or a `list` of cars, your solution is appropriate (see [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in Python). However, keep in mind that XML is ordered and the produced JSON uses a `dict` which is unordered! Is there any reason why you wouldn't use XML directly, e.g. with [lxml](http://lxml.de/)?

Comment: in my real code it has a different name, but i fixed the code above code too, thanks. - My first try was with ElementTree, but i had some encoding trouble... i thoung maybe this way was better... maybe i was wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is of course not an elegant way, but this is what i have done to get the code run (if someone hase the same probleme an found this via google):

```
import xmltodict

def guaranteed_list(x):
    if not x:
        return []
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return x
    else:
        return [x]

mydict = xmltodict.parse(xmlstringResults)    
for carsInGarage in guaranteed_list(mydict['garage']['car']):
    # do something...
```

but i thing i will write my code again and "use XML directly" as one of the comments said.

Answer (score 39):

This problem is discussed in [this issue on Github](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/14). The xmltodict package now supports

```
d = xmltodict.parse(s, force_list={'car'})
```

Although this still doesn't create an empty list if the field is absent.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to XML parsing in Python so this saved me a ton of work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the existing answers, xmltodict now also supports the following to force *everything* to be a list:

```py
xml = xmltodict.parse(s, force_list=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the combination of

1)

```
json_dict = xmltodict.parse(s, force_list={'item'})
```

And

2)

```
# Removes a level in python dict if it has only one specific key
# 
# Examples: 
# recursive_skip_dict_key_level({"c": {"a": "b"}}, "c")  # -> {"a", "b"}
# recursive_skip_dict_key_level({"c": ["a", "b"]}, "c") # -> ["a", "b"]
#
def recursive_skip_dict_key_level(d, skipped_key):
    if issubclass(type(d), dict):
        if list(d.keys()) == [skipped_key]:
            return recursive_skip_dict_key_level(d[skipped_key], skipped_key)
        else:
            for key in d.keys():
                d[key] = recursive_skip_dict_key_level(d[key], skipped_key)
            return d
    elif issubclass(type(d), list):
        new_list = []
        for e in d: 
            new_list.append(recursive_skip_dict_key_level(e, skipped_key))
        return new_list
    else: 
        return d
```

3. 

```
# Removes None values from a dict
# 
# Examples: 
# recursive_remove_none({"a": None})  # -> {}
# recursive_remove_none([None]) # -> []
#
def recursive_remove_none(d):
    if issubclass(type(d), dict):
        new_dict = {}
        for key in d.keys():
            if not (d[key] is None):
                new_dict[key] = recursive_remove_none(d[key])
        return new_dict
    elif issubclass(type(d), list):
        new_list = []
        for e in d: 
            if not (e is None):
                new_list.append(recursive_remove_none(e))
        return new_list
    else: 
        return d
```

```
json_dict = recursive_skip_dict_key_level(json_dict, "item")
json_dict = recursive_remove_none(json_dict)
```

to interpret any "item" XML-elements as lists.